# Excel search function with a list of things - array behaves weird?

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a list of substrings and need to check if the text string in my cell contains any of these substrings. Exactly like here: https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-one-of-many-things

However, the ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MySubstrings,A3)) behaves strangely. Instead of checking A3 against a list of substrings like ISNUMBER(SEARCH({dog, cat, egg},A3)) it automatically populates three subsequent cells to show results for checking A3 against every item on my list, one by one.

[search without curly brackets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTutB.png)

And when I enter the same thing as an array formula, it only checks for occurrence of the first substring from my list, in this case "dog".

[search with curly brackets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iciAC.png)

Why does this not work? Thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `SUMPRODUCT` function as in the exceljet example. The argument passed to `SUMPRODUCT` is an array (in your example, a 1-by-3 array of `TRUE` or `FALSE`), which `SUMPRODUCT` turns into a single value (0 or 1):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"dog","cat","egg"},A3)))>0
```

An alternative formulation would be to wrap `ISNUMBER` with the `OR` function (still no need to enter as an array):

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"dog","cat","egg"},A3)))
```